# Shorter phrase or idiom for "progressively disclose"?

Tags: terminology, progressive-disclosure

This question might be better suited for [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/), but since it seems *so* specific to UX, I figured I'd try it here first:

**Is there a (shorter, easier) word or phrase I could use to say that something is removed from the main view and "disclosed progressively"?**

Not necessarily looking for a mainstream word/phrase, just one I could adopt to make it less awkward to talk about this concept in daily design conversations.

Examples of usage:

> These form fields would be _____ since they are only important in rare cases.

> I'd like to see what happens if we _____ this component, since users were complaining about information overload on this screen.

> What if we didn't _____ that piece of the workflow? We could include it right before the confirmation step, so people don't miss it as often.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but what about "omit" or "omitted"?

Comment: @WilliamAnderson Shorter, yes, but it seems like it implies that you're taking it out entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jakob Nielsen](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/progressive-disclosure/) uses the term **defer** which I think conveys the idea accurately. The same article also uses the term **hide** which makes sense as well - hidden items can be shown when needed.

Quote the article:

> Progressive disclosure *defers* advanced or rarely used features to
>   a secondary screen, making applications easier to learn and less
>   error-prone.

> Staged disclosure would *defer* the payment details to a secondary
>   screen.

> The more features you can *defer*, the simpler your design, but if you
>   divide the task into too many steps, users get bogged down by excess
>   navigation.

> By *hiding* the advanced settings, progressive disclosure helps novice
>   users avoid mistakes and saves them the time they would have spent
>   contemplating features that they don't need.

Comment: Could you include some examples in your answer, just in case the link dies in the future?

Comment: Good point, I added a few quotes from the article.